# sidebar commands (for opening and collapsing explorer)

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm looking for commands to show and collapse the explorer (so I can configure some vim keybindings).

Best I can find is "workbench.view.explorer", but this doesn't collapse it.  Anyone know what command I'm looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To **toggle the sidebar** you can use the following command:

```
{ "key": "ctrl+b",                "command": "workbench.action.toggleSidebarVisibility" },
```

With the following commands you can switch to one specific sidebar view:

```
{ "key": "ctrl+shift+d",          "command": "workbench.view.debug" },
{ "key": "ctrl+shift+e",          "command": "workbench.view.explorer" },
{ "key": "ctrl+shift+x",          "command": "workbench.view.extensions" },
{ "key": "ctrl+shift+g",          "command": "workbench.view.scm" },
{ "key": "ctrl+shift+f",          "command": "workbench.view.search",
```